# Object data randomly changed Fabricjs

Tags: javascript, fabricjs

I got a piece of code that records mouse clicks and draws a polygon at the end.
After it draws the polygon it stringifies the array of coordinates ready for future processing.

The problem i am facing is that what is recorded and drawn and what is stringified are two completely different sets of data.

e.g.

```
(index):169 Mouse click at 543 179
(index):171 Object {x: 543, y: 179} contains value, match as per mouse click
(index):169 Mouse click at 310 592
(index):171 Object {x: 310, y: 592} contains value, match as per mouse click
(index):169 Mouse click at 735 480
(index):171 Object {x: 735, y: 480} contains value, match as per mouse click
(index):246 [{"x":20.5,"y":-206.5},{"x":-212.5,"y":206.5},{"x":212.5,"y":94.5}] is stringified value
```

JS

```
    var coords = [];
    var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('canvas');

    canvas.on('mouse:down', function (options) {
                getCoordinates(options);
        });



    $('.drawReady').click(function(){
           drawMyPolygon(coords, 1);
           stringifyTheData();
    });

function drawMyPolygon(retData, tmpId) {
            var polygon = new fabric.Polygon(retData, {
                fill: 'purple',
                selectable: true,
                lockMovementX: true,
                lockMovementY: true,
                id: tmpId
            });

            canvas.add(polygon);

        };
    function getCoordinates(options) {
      var pointer = canvas.getPointer(event.e);
      coords.push({x: pointer.x, y: pointer.y});
    }

    function stringifyTheData() {
      var retVal = JSON.stringify(coords);
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are using fabricJS prior version 1.6.0
In 1.5.0 fabricjs was modifying the point array while now does not.

The cange consisted in substracting to every point the top,left and half the width of polygon, to bring it origin centered.

Either update OR clone the point array before passing to the polygon.

Comment: Bingo that did it. Weird problem. Updated to 1.6.1 and problem is gone instantly. There goes 3 hrs of debugging for nada.

Comment: Yes because we realized it was weird and we fixed it.

Comment: Bahaha, i like it.